# Validation not preventing destroy - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Customer` record with a many to many association with `Location`.

I currently check/uncheck the locations I want for a specific customer on the edit customer page. When I uncheck all of the locations and hit submit, the locations are deleted from my model and an error is thrown from my validation. I would've expected the locations to not be deleted since I have the validation that requires they exist which is what I need.

My validation in the `Customer` model.

```
validates :locations, presence: true
```

My view:

```
<% @locations.each do |i| %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= hidden_field_tag "customer[location_ids][]", '' %>
        <%= check_box_tag "customer[location_ids][]", i.id, @customer.location_ids.include?(i.id) %>
        <%= i.name %>
      </li>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.assign_attributes(params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :middle_initial, :last_name, :location_ids => []))
    @customer.save!
```

`.save!` causes the following error:

```
error Locations can't be blank
```

However, when you refresh the page or review the database records, the location references are destroyed and I also see they are destroyed from the CLI. I don't understand why the validation doesn't prevent the location references from being destroyed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they all destroyed, or all but one? You don't validate that they all have to be there, only that at least one has to.

Comment: @EmilKampp They are all deleted.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for mass assigning nested attributes through `assign_attributes`? It seems that there may be a quirk there about deleting records being done without validations, and your validations are called only when you call `save!`.

Comment: You could use `validates_associated :customer` in your `Location` model. This method runs the validation on the association. Though, i'm not sure if this happens on delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem which people run into with ActiveRecord.

### The problem

The `location_ids=` setter method will immediately add/update/delete records, which is alluded to in the [ActiveRecord Associations guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-singular-ids-ids). That behavior often surprises developers and is often undesired. I almost always avoid it.

In your code you are first calling `assign_attributes` which in turn calls `location_ids=`. Changes are immediately persisted to the records. Subsequently, when `save!` is called, it opens a new transaction. If a validation error occurs then only the changes in that transaction will be rolled back, and those exclude the already-persisted changes made by `location_ids=`.

```
@customer.assign_attributes(params...)  # location_ids are saved outside of the `save!` transaction.
@customer.save!                         # validation errors will cause a rollback only to this point, excluding changes from the previous line.
```

### An Easy Solution

Use `update_attributes!` to replace both `assign_attributes` and `save!`. This will have the effect of wrapping all changes in a transaction such that a rollback will undo everything like you want. Yay!

```
@customer.update_attributes!(params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :middle_initial, :last_name, :location_ids => []))
```

### An Alternative Approach

Sometimes it might not be possible to avoid separate calls to `assign_attributes` and `save`. This makes things much more complicated. No option that I can think of for this case is trivial.

One possible solution is to use nested attributes to update/destroy the child records.

`location_ids` is really a shortcut for updating each Location record associated with the given Customer. Instead of relying on that you can use nested attributes in your forms to update the locations. This method can take advantage of the `mark_for_destruction` ([link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html)) feature for autosave. Describing a full solution for this approach would be prohibitively lengthy, but it has proven to be very effective for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead can you do this. For validations, we should be using `before_destory` callback. This should prevent the locations from deleting, when you're saving a customer when you have unchecked all locations.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  before_destroy :check_for_locations?

  private

  def check_for_locations?
    errors.add(:base, "cannot delete customer with locations") unless locations.count == 0
    errors.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, but I'm not worried about deleting a customer. The issue is when I update a customer and pass an array of location ids. If I pass a `nil` array, then the customer is updated without any locations. I'm trying to prevent the customer from having all of its location references destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that ActiveRecord is more reliable in validating the existence of associated records by asking it to validate the length of the associated `*_ids` array. In your case:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
  validates :location_ids, length: { minimum: 1 }
end
```